# Connect two actions to one reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

Can I connect two actions to one reducer?
What I want to do is fetch an object (that will have the same property types)
From two different actions and then add it into the state, I want it to be like this:
If I call action1 the state should be the result of action1, if I then call action2 the result of action1 in the state should be overwritten by the result of action2. Therefor I want to use two actions connected to one reducer. So they use the same property in the store  (state).

**First Action**

```
export function projectHasErrored(bool){
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_HAS_ERRORED',
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

export function projectIsLoading(bool){
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function projectFetchDataSuccess(project){
    console.log(project)
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_FETCH_SUCCESS',
        project
    };
}

export function projectFetchData(url, {owner, projectName}){
    console.log(projectName + "! hejhej")
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(projectIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                owner,
                projectName
            }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw Error(response.statusText)
                }

                dispatch(projectIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((project) => dispatch(projectFetchDataSuccess(project)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(projectHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

**2nd action**

```
export function lastProjectHasErrored(bool){
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_HAS_ERRORED',
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

export function lastProjectIsLoading(bool){
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function projectFetchDataSuccess(project){
    console.log(project)
    return {
        type: 'PROJECT_FETCH_SUCCESS',
        project
    };
}

export function lastProjectFetchData(url, owner){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(lastProjectIsLoading(true));
        fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                owner
            }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw Error(response.statusText)
                }

                dispatch(lastProjectIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((project) => dispatch(lastProjectFetchDataSuccess(project)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(lastProjectHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

**The Reducer**

```
export function projectHasErrored(state = false, action){
    switch(action.type){
      case 'PROJECT_HAS_ERRORED':
        return action.hasErrored;

      default:
        return state
    }
}

export function projectIsLoading(state = false, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'PROJECT_IS_LOADING':
      return action.isLoading;

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function project(state = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'PROJECT_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return action.project;

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing then?your reducers should be work.You can use two action for one reducers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can connect one or more actions to a reducer.

//action1.js

```
 `export function Add(data){
      return (dispatch)=>{
          dispatch(type:'SET_DATA',data})   
      } 
  }`
```

//action2.js

```
`export function Sub(value){
     return (dispatch)=>{
         dispatch({type:'SET_VALUE',value})
     }
 }
```

Now in your reducer.js

```
const initialState={
  data:''
  value:''
}
export default function initialReducer(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_DATA':{
         return {
              ...state,
              data:action.data
         }
         }
         case 'SET_VALUE':{
         return {
              ...state,
              data:action.value
         }
         }
         default: {return state}
    }
}
```

Therefore , the actions would be connected to the same reducer.

Comment: Can they have same action.type?

Comment: they can.. but the cases(declared in switch) must be different. So that the action sets the corresponding value correctly

Comment: Okey so they cant go into the same Case? I mean they return the same data, and i want the old state from this reducer to be the new result

Comment: In the code snippet given above, you have created a  separate reducer for each action dispatched. Are you using combined Reducer???. If you are using that , it must be working ,As actions only correspond to the 'Case' mentioned in the reducer. Also make sure to return an Object from the reducer as actions must always return plain text objects

Comment: You can try out the reducer Code that I have mentioned above